# dyld: Symbol not found after importing .xcframework

Tags: ios, xcode, xcframework

I've created an `.xcframework` using this script:

```sh
FRAMEWORK_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
SCHEME=${PROJECT_NAME}
DISPLAY_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}

echo "Archiving ${FRAMEWORK_NAME} for iOS simulator..." >> framework.log
xcodebuild archive \
    -workspace "${PROJECT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcworkspace" \
    -scheme "${SCHEME}" \
    -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    -archivePath "${PROJECT_DIR}/Archives/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-iOS-Simulator" \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

echo "Archiving ${FRAMEWORK_NAME} for iOS..." >> framework.log
xcodebuild archive \
    -workspace "${PROJECT_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcworkspace" \
    -scheme "${SCHEME}" \
    -destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
    -sdk iphoneos \
    -archivePath "${PROJECT_DIR}/Archives/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-iOS" \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

echo "Creating the ${FRAMEWORK_NAME} XC Framework..." >> framework.log
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
    -framework "${PROJECT_DIR}/Archives/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-iOS-Simulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/${DISPLAY_NAME}.framework" \
    -framework "${PROJECT_DIR}/Archives/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-iOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/${DISPLAY_NAME}.framework" \
    -output "${PROJECT_DIR}/${DISPLAY_NAME}.xcframework"
```

However, when I import the `.xcframework` in another project I get this error:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _$s12ReachabilityAAC10ConnectionO11unavailableyA2DmFWC
>
> > Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A5315543-8323-4270-8D40-8BB1C940801C/App.app/Frameworks/Framework.framework/Framework
> >
> > Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A5315543-8323-4270-8D40-8BB1C940801C/App.app/Frameworks/Reachability.framework/Reachability
>
> in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A5315543-8323-4270-8D40-8BB1C940801C/App.app/Frameworks/Framework.framework/Framework
>
> ---
>
> dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
> DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUTools.framework/libglInterpose.dylib:/usr/lib/libMTLCapture.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib

Every example I've seen on creating an `.xcframework` doesn't archive using an `.xcworkspace`, so I'm thinking my issue must be related to that. I need to archive the `.xcworkspace` because the framework has its own Cocoapod dependencies (`Reachability` being one of them), but the project I'm integrating with includes those dependencies.

Has anyone successfully created an `.xcframework` from source code that has Pod dependencies?

Comment: I've created an xcframework from source code that has Pod dependencies.

Comment: Did you do anything differently? Can you share the commands you used?

Comment: Adam, the script seems identical actually. Hard to see. Can you update your Cocoapods library, please? I saw a few posts on GitHub. I Used my own lib: https://github.com/gurhub/surmagic. But I think it might be related to the cocoapods version.